# Помогите найти ошибку в html коде

Tags: html

Помогите найти ошибку

```
<TABLE align="center" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="1250" height="351" border="0" background="/img/1.jpg"> 
<TR>
<td></td>
<TD colspan="0" height="348">
<div align="left" style="padding-top:150px;"><font size=2 color=#DADBD7><br><b> 
</b></div>
<tr><td width="60"></td><td width="340"> </td><td width="510"></td><td colspan="4"></td></tr></TABLE>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" width="1250" height="23" style="border:1px solid #262626;background:url('/img/2.gif');">
 <tr>
 <td width="50%" align="left" style="font-size:10px;padding-left:10px;"><a href="$HOME_PAGE_LINK$" title="Главная"><!--<s5176>-->Главная<!--</s>--></a><?if($USERS_ON$)?><?if($USER_LOGGED_IN$)?> | <a href="$PERSONAL_PAGE_LINK$" title="Мой профиль"><!--<s5214>-->Мой профиль<!--</s>--></a><?else?> | <a href="$REGISTER_LINK$" title="Регистрация"><!--<s3089>-->Регистрация<!--</s>--></a><?endif?><?endif?> <?if($USERS_ON$)?><?if($USER_LOGGED_IN$)?> | <a href="$LOGOUT_LINK$" title="Выход"><!--<s5164>-->Выход<!--</s>--></a><?else?> | <a href="$LOGIN_LINK$" title="Вход"><!--<s3087>-->Вход<!--</s>--></a><?endif?><?endif?></td>
 <td width="50%" align="right" style="font-size:10px;padding-right:10px;"><?if($USERS_ON$)?><?if($USER_LOGGED_IN$)?><!--<s5200>-->Вы вошли как<!--</s>--> <a href="$PERSONAL_PAGE_LINK$" title="Мой профиль"><b>$USERNAME$</b></a> | <!--<s3167>-->Группа<!--</s>--> "<u>$USER_GROUP$</u>"<?else?><!--<s5212>-->Приветствую Вас<!--</s>--> <b>$USERNAME$</b><?endif?><?endif?> <?if($RSS_LINK$)?>| <a href="$RSS_LINK$" title="RSS">RSS</a><?endif?></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @selenia Что, по Вашему мнению, здесь работает на так?

Answer (score 1):

Лекго.

1. Нет аттрибута align в данном случае. У таблицы, например. Но он есть у рисунка
2. так же: height, background. Кроме того, числа в них должны содержать размерность, коль скоро они отличны от 0. Например: `height="357px"`. А вообще, это все надо в CSS запихать
3. У фонта нет аттрибута сайз. И вообще фонт лучше заменить `<span></span>`, а свойства описать в CSS
4. элемент `<u>` так же надо заменять `text-decoration: underline`

Все это, исходя из предположения, что разметка HTML 4.01

```
<table align="center" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="1250" height="351" border="0" background="/img/1.jpg"> 
<TR>
<td>
</td>
<td colspan="0" height="348">
    <div align="left" style="padding-top:150px;">
        <font size=2 color=#DADBD7><br><b></b>
    </div>
</td>
<tr>
    <td width="60"></td>
    <td width="340"> </td>
    <td width="510"></td>
    <td colspan="4"></td>
</tr></table>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" width="1250" height="23" style="border:1px solid #262626;background:url('/img/2.gif');">
 <tr>
    <td width="50%" align="left" style="font-size:10px;padding-left:10px;">
        <a href="$HOME_PAGE_LINK$" title="Главная">
            <!--<s5176>-->Главная<!--</s>-->
        </a><?php
            if($USERS_ON){
            ?><?php
                if($USER_LOGGED_IN){
                ?> | <a href="$PERSONAL_PAGE_LINK$" title="Мой профиль">
                        <!--<s5214>-->Мой профиль<!--</s>-->
                    </a><?php 
                }else{
                        ?> | <a href="$REGISTER_LINK$" title="Регистрация">
                                <!--<s3089>-->Регистрация<!--</s>-->
                            </a><?php
                }?><?php
            }?> <?php
            if($USERS_ON){
                ?><?php 
                if($USER_LOGGED_IN){
                    ?> | <a href="$LOGOUT_LINK$" title="Выход">
                    <!--<s5164>-->Выход<!--</s>-->
                        </a><?php
                }else{
                    ?> | <a href="$LOGIN_LINK$" title="Вход">
                    <!--<s3087>-->Вход<!--</s>--></a><?php
                }?><?php
            }?></td>
    <td width="50%" align="right" style="font-size:10px;padding-right:10px;"><?php
        if($USERS_ON){
            ?><?php
            if($USER_LOGGED_IN){
                ?>
                <!--<s5200>-->Вы вошли как<!--</s>--> 
                <a href="$PERSONAL_PAGE_LINK$" title="Мой профиль">
                <b>$USERNAME$</b>
                </a> | <!--<s3167>-->Группа<!--</s>--> "<u>$USER_GROUP$</u>"<?php
            }else{
                ?><!--<s5212>-->Приветствую Вас<!--</s>--> <b>$USERNAME$</b><?
            }?><?php
        }?> <?php
        if($RSS_LINK){
            ?>| <a href="$RSS_LINK$" title="RSS">RSS</a><?php
        }?></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Извините мне мою некомпетентность. Но не могли бы вы написать правильный код. , т.е уже исправленный. Я в HTML  - не просто чайник, а ....

Comment: есть мааааленькая проблема. У вас ошибки, мешающие отобразиться странице не в HTML, а в PHP. Сейчас пришлю.

Comment: Ловите. Только учтите, что это ШАБЛОН, вообще-то...